# Is the directory structure expected for namespaced routes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've created a `namespaced` route called `checkout`.

I have the following in `router.js`.

```
// router.js
this.route('checkout', function() {
  this.resource('payments', function() {
  });
});
```

The following routes can be accessed via:

```
http://localhost/checkout/payments
```

However, the controllers, templates, routes for `payment`, don't exist in the the `checkout` directory. I would have imagined:

```
app/controllers/checkout/payments/index.js
app/routes/checkout/payments/index.js
app/templates/checkout/payments/index.hbs
```

But instead they exist and can be accessed by Ember in:

```
app/controllers/payments/index.js
app/routes/payments/index.js
app/templates/payments/index.hbs
```

Is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That it works at all is partially due to what Asgaroth describes: resources reset the namespace so in your example ember-cli is looking for a class `Payments` rather than `CheckoutPayments`, and partially due to ember-cli supporting two directory layouts (the regular one and the "pod" layout). While it builds the application it takes the name of classes from the file *or* the directory, depending on which is most appropriate.

You are basically mixing and matching the two approaches to the file system layout, which is why it works at all. But it would be incredibly difficult to figure out what belongs to what without a better structure in place.

Instead I'm using the `ember generate --pod ...` structure with them (which should become recommended for Ember 2.0), which results in a somewhat similar structure for my files as in your question:

```
app/map
├── debug
│   ├── controller.js
│   ├── route.js
│   └── template.hbs
├── index
│   ├── controller.js
│   └── template.hbs
├── settings
│   ├── controller.js
│   └── template.hbs
├── systems
│   ├── system
│   │   ├── route.js
│   │   └── template.hbs
│   ├── controller.js
│   ├── route.js
│   └── template.hbs
├── controller.js
└── template.hbs
```

And yes, you can nest routes (since Ember 1.7 or so) and with ES6 modules it brings little benefit to use resources over routes. I've stopped using them, as per the structure above my `router.js` now is a rather trivial:

```
this.route( 'map', function() {
  this.route( 'systems', function() {
    this.route( 'system', { path: ':system_id' } );
  });
  this.route( 'settings' );
  this.route( 'debug' );
});
```

I can highly recommend the pod structure for your routers, controllers, mixins and components .. it takes some getting used to though, and your editor has to show directory names to be able to know what you are editing.

Comment: Do you have a link indicating/mentioning that `resources` will be going away on Ember 2.0?

Comment: Oh, re-reading the comments here there's nothing saying they're going away, just that it is easier to not use them. Ember ~1.7 or so allows to nest routes, ES6 modules make long module names irrelevant, and just nesting routes then makes it easier to prepare for Ember 2.0: https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97

Comment: Where do you store your models?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can nest `routes` within `routes` are you sure you are not talking about `resources`?

[A resource always resets the namespace.](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources)

> The route, controller, and view class names for the comments resource
>   are not prefixed with Post. **Resources always reset the namespace**,
>   ensuring that the classes can be re-used between multiple parent
>   resources and that class names don't get longer the deeper nested the
>   resources are.

*emphasys mine*

Comment: I meant `resource` not `route`. Let me edit. So if `resource` overrides the `namespace`. Is this supposed to be normal? Or is there another way to preserve the directory structure of a `namespace`?